# Move HTML element upwards on hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to move an HTML element up about 10px whenever a user hovers their mouse over it. I did some research on w3schools, but I could not find any information that helped me. Most of their animation examples were using keyframes and I'm pretty sure that's not what I need because I'm trying to trigger an animation when somebody hovers over the element. I could be wrong though and that's why I'm posting here.

Here's the element I'm trying to move:

```
<div id="arrow">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-2x"></i></a>
</div>
```

For my CSS:

```
#arrow {
  padding-top: 310px;
  color: #5C6B7E;
  position: relative;
  /* some kind of animation property here? */
}

#arrow:hover {
  /* new properties once user hovers */
}
```

I'm not sure what I need to add to make the element animate up, the examples on w3schools weren't of much help. If anybody could point me in the right direction I would be extremely appreciative. Thank you Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can use keyframe animations on hover; one way or another you're setting a style change on hover. Although in this instance you only need to move from point A to point B so keyframes aren't necessary (check-out CSS Transitions).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You need not use keyframes for this simple animation. Just CSS transition is enough.

Set the `transition` property in the initial state style rules with the duration.

**Edit:** I just noticed that there is a flicker at the bottom, it can be removed by setting the styles on the icon and hover on the parent.

```css
#arrow i {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: top ease 0.5s;
}
#arrow:hover i {
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="arrow">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-2x"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

You could also try applying a negative `margin-top` on hover if your element is absolutely positioned:

```css
div {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<div>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I came across this while trying to solve an issue I had with getting an element to move when hovering over it with my mouse. None of the above worked, so I thought I'd share the solution I came up with on a test I ran:

```css
.item {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  transition: transform ease 300ms;
}

.item:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">TEST</div>
```